# How do I order an ArrayList of objects by one of the objects attributes?

Tags: c#, .net, arraylist

How do I order an ArrayList of objects by one of the objects attributes?

And please do not suggest any technique to do with `List<T>`. For my current software, using `List<T>` is out of the question.

Comment: There is an example on the [MSDN page for ArrayList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0e743hdt(v=vs.110).aspx). Did you try anything using that example as a starting point?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight LINQ doesn't work well with non-generic collections anyway. You could create generic collection from `ArrayList`, sort it and create new `ArrayList` with sorted items in there but I don't think that's a good idea. As Steve pointed out there already is `Sort` method defined on `ArrayList`.

Comment: using LINQ is also out of option because I am coding on a legacy software and am asked not to use LINQ for this. My arrayList contains many objects such a X,Y,Z, etc. and I want to sort the arraylist based on only one object's property such as Y's. Can someone suggest me any idea of doing that?

Comment: What have you tried and what is the problem? What do you mean *attributes*? Attributes are applied at the class level, not the instance level. Do you mean properties? Do you want to sort by a specific property? What happens if an object is of a different type?

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek Can just use `Cast<T>` or `OfType<T>` on the `ArrayList` before the linq expression.

Comment: Does "don't use LINQ" mean you can't use something like `OfType<T>` ? Otherwise you'll have to create a custom comparer and cast each item against all expected types

Comment: yes, I actually meant by properties. I implemented a class and the class has different properties, which are of different kind. Some properties are int, double or string. And everytime each object of that class with all the different properties are saved in the arraylist. I want to sort the complete arraylist based on a property which is of type string. Does anyone has any idea about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement `IComparer` for your entity like:

```
public class MyClassComparer : IComparer<MyClass>
{
    public int Compare(MyClass _x, MyClass _y)
    {
        return _x.MyProp.CompareTo(_y.MyProp);
    }
}
```

And pass it to [ArrayList.Sort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0e743hdt(v=vs.110).aspx) like:

```
myArrayList.Sort(new MyClassComparer());
```

Comment: According to the comments, the array may contain different types

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos and what that changes? Approach will remain the same. Maybe we can operate with interfaces instead of concrete class or maybe make comparer from object and compare stuff using reflection.

Comment: It means that you have to check the type of each object, you can't use a generic comparer. Actually, IComparer<T> doesn't implement IComparer so it cant' be passed to ArrayList.Sort

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos what about **IComparer<object>** or **IComparer<ISomeCommonInterfaceOfAllObjectsInArrayList>** and yes that means also that author need to replace **MyProp** and etc but that just small details about implementation and question wasn't about that

Comment: As I wrote, IComparer<T> doesn't implement IComparer so you can't use it, the code won't compile. The "small details" of type checking and casting are what cause the problem in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement your own comparer ,  [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0e743hdt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This is an example written using LinqPad that could help you.
Loosely based on the MSDN example.
You just need to use your own class instead of the sample used here

```
void Main()
{
    ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
    al.Add(new Person() {Name="Steve", Age=53});
    al.Add(new Person() {Name="Thomas", Age=30});

    al.Sort(new PersonComparer());

    foreach(Person p in al)
        Console.WriteLine(p.Name + " " + p.Age);

}

class Person
{
    public string Name;
    public int Age;
}
class PersonComparer : IComparer
{

    int IComparer.Compare( Object x, Object y )  
    {
        if (x == null)
            return (y == null) ? 0 : 1;

        if (y == null)
            return -1;

        Person p1 = x as Person;
        Person p2 = y as Person;

        // Uncomment this to sort by Name 
        // return( (new CaseInsensitiveComparer()).Compare( p1.Name, p2.Name) );

        return( p1.Age - p2.Age );
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks Steve. :D
this worked for me. :D
SUPER HELPFUL!!